# In Angular with Flux pattern, should "dumb" components emit events or trigger actions?

Tags: angular, redux, flux

There are a lot of discussion about **smart and dumb components** when using the Flux pattern with Angular.

I ended up making my smart component (say `ItemsListComponent`) "manage" the app state (the slice of app state). The dump component is `ItemCardComponent`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of state$.items | async">
  <app-item-card [item]="item" (delete)="handleDelete($event)"></app-item-card>
</div>
```

My `ItemCardComponent` receive `item` as input. But then, should emit events (**approach A**) or trigger actions by itself (**approach B**)?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-card',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ item.title }}
      <button (click)="delete.emit(item.id)">Delete</button>
      <button (click)="toggleFavorite(item.id)">Favorite</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ItemCardComponent {
  @Input()
  item: any;

  // Approach B
  @Output()
  delete: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  // Approach A
  toggleFavorite(id: number) {
    // Assume that we have access the store here
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Item] ToggleFavorite', payload: id });
  }
}
```

With approach A you have a lot of boilerplate code (since the smart component should handle the event and then trigger actions). With approach B, we are coupling the dump component to the state.

Answer (score 0):

We can start with dumb component that is connected to the store directly (by dispatching an event).

The next step is to wait until we actually need to reuse this component. Than we refactor and separate smart/dump components.

> A premature optimization ([generalization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureGeneralization)?) is the root of all evil